# Regex for Heka to read Monolog logfile

Tags: regex, kibana, monolog

I am trying to get Heka to read my Monolog files (so I can view them using Kibana), but it keeps telling me there is no match.

Here is my `match_regex` from my Heka config:

```
match_regex = "^\\[(?P<Timestamp>.*)\\] (?P<Channel>.+?)\\.(?P<Severity>[A-Z]+): (?P<Message>.*)"
```

And here is a sample line from the log

```
[2014-03-24 19:07:08] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate"
```

according to regex101 ([see here](http://regex101.com/r/dP6dB7)) the regex is perfectly fine. Yet hela tells me no match.

Could someone please point me in the right direction, I spent all day yesterday trying to get this to work.

**EDIT**: the only documentation I can seem to find regarding Heka and Monolog are these slides [here](http://slides.seld.be/?file=2013-12-13%20Application%20monitoring%20with%20Heka%20and%20statsd.html#20)

**EDIT**: I just found this : https://regoio.herokuapp.com/

This tells me that it should work using the following:

```
match_regex = '^\[(?P<Timestamp>.*)\] (?P<Channel>.+?)\.(?P<Severity>[A-Z]+): (?P<Message>.*)'
```

But it's not.

Comment: Maybe because the regex starts with `^`? Maybe you need to set the regex multiline modifier or something? That makes `^` match the start of lines too instead of only the start of the complete string. http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: it seems the ^ was not the issue, it seems my lack of attention was the issue, i had indeed tried with and without the ^     but was not getting anything, just because i forgot to setup the outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearly i was not properly awake yesterday, after making sure the regex was correct 15 times, i realised i had forgotten

```
[LogOutput]
 message_matcher = "TRUE"

[ElasticSearchOutput]
 message_matcher = "TRUE"
```

in my `hekad.toml` file

My complete file now looks like this :

```
[pos_log]
type = "LogfileInput"
logfile = "/home/sam/git/PosBranch/app/logs/dev.log"
decoder = "monolog_decoder"

[monolog_decoder]
type = "PayloadRegexDecoder"
match_regex = '^\[(?P<Timestamp>.*)\] (?P<Channel>.+?)\.(?P<Severity>[A-Z]+): (?P<Message>.*)'
timestamp_layout = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
timestamp_location = "UTC" # optional, default value

[monolog_decoder.severity_map]
DEBUG = 7
INFO = 6
NOTICE = 5
WARNING = 4
ERROR = 3
CRITICAL = 2
ALERT = 1
EMERGENCY = 0

[monolog_decoder.message_fields]
Type = "monolog_log"
Logger = "sam"
Hostname = "local"
Channel = "%Channel%"
Message = "%Message%"
Payload = ""

[LogOutput]
 message_matcher = "TRUE"

[ElasticSearchOutput]
 message_matcher = "TRUE"
```

and messages are now rolling into kibana :)